# How to make azure image load faster?

Tags: image, download, blob, azure-blob-storage

Loading time of images from the blob is very slow
something like 3-4 secs
what can i do to make it fast?

[image: firebug print screen]

Comment: i also tried the cdn but it is slower

Comment: I hate to ask this, but did you check which region the storage account is setup?  I think the default region is south Asia.

Answer (score 0):

If this is slow from multiple sources, the issue is likely in the client. You can turn Azure Storage Analytics on and then compare the server time to the e2e time. Server time is the time that the request took to process on the server, e2e time is the time the request took end-to-end, including network transmission. The difference between the two tells you how much time you are spending on the network.